# MongoDB 2.0.9 IndexStats

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to get the index usage statistics in a mongoDB 2.0.9.

I found a similar question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44813787/how-to-check-index-usage-in-mongodb but this only applies to versions 3.2 and up.

Any assistance will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The [`$indexstats` command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexStats/) was added for the MongoDB 3.2 server release in Dec 2015. Without server support for measuring or logging index use, I'm not aware of any obvious workaround short of modifying the [2.0.x server code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/tree/v2.0) and building a custom server.

MongoDB 2.0 is a relatively ancient server version: it was first released in Sept 2011 and reached End-of-Life in March 2013. I'd strongly recommend planning to upgrade to a modern & supported version of MongoDB (currently 3.4+, although 3.4 will reach EOL in Jan 2020). There are numerous essential bug fixes, stability, and security improvements since 2.0.

Comment: Thanks you @Stennie, we are looking into upgrading for a while and hopefully will get it done soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the below js against the database you want and it would print the list of indexes that 0 access:

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collection){
    db.getCollection(collection).aggregate([{
        $indexStats: {}
        }, {
            $match: {
                "accesses.ops": NumberLong(0)
                }
        }]).forEach(function(doc) {
            print("Index Key:" + JSON.stringify(doc.key) + "in collection" + "has" + doc.accesses.ops + "accesses");
            });
});
```

Hope this helps your need until you upgrade your cluster!

Thank you!

-Anban